# Printing entire row of table based on changing cell value and then clearing it in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, vba, search

I am making an archive system that allows for a user to search for a machine by business unit, then exact machine. Each machine has its own details associated with it-- all of them put into a table.

The table looks like this:

| Unit | Machine | PC | Software |

The user will insert the unit and machine into a cell within the "query sheet" using a drop-down list, and then press a button. I want the program to look for the machine within the "archive sheet", find the row that the machine is in, and then print all of the details to the query sheet, under the "search bar".

I also wanted to try having another button that would clear the query-- that is to say that would clear the cells with all of the researched information.

I am very inexperienced with Excel, and I have been using VBA to make all of this program work. I'm sure this is simple, but I just need a little bit of guidance on where to go from here.

The story is:

1. User enters Unit value in QuerySheet
2. User enters Machine value
3. User presses button
4. Program goes to ArchiveSheet
5. Program finds row with machine details within the Unit Table
6. Information transfer of that row to cells underneath the "search bar" cells within QuerySheet
7. Clear all information associated with query AFTER "clear" button is pressed.

All I could parse is just simply copying it from one sheet to another? But it's completely conditional on the machine picked, and there over 100 machines-- I don't really want to write a program that requires me to do a conditional statement for every machine possible.

Here's an idea that I had, but I don't know if I'm on the right track.

```
Sub() Search Function

Dim querybox as Variant
querybox = Range("B2")

If querybox = machine1 Then 
Sheets("ArchiveSheet").Cells("*stuck*").CopySheets("QuerySheet").Cells("A4:D4")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using native Excel features instead of VBA in your case.

For example, for clause 1,2 you may use Data Validation tool. You may use formula to extract unique values from the column. So, you will have two Dropdowns containing all the units and machines. You may further make machine dropdown be dependent from the Unit dropdown value. In this case you don't need to have a button to address data sheet.

Clauses 3-5 are redundant.

Clause 6: Under dropdowns you want to have an area with selected data. The best choice, to my opinion, is to use Filter function with parameters from dropdown.

Clause 7: you may use Match function, with parameters from dropdowns as well, to detect row, which you need to remove. Use VBA to remove this row.

Also, if you modify business logic, you may use native Excel forms for your purpose.
I hope I've given you another idea.

BTW, since you are not familiar with Excel and VBA, try Python. You will achieve your goal faster.

Comment: I appreciate the help! Yeah, I misunderstood the how the native FILTER function worked-- it seems to actually apply fine for what I need at the moment. I have a lot of machines sorted into tables, and I was under the impression that the FILTER function would require a lot more personal tweaking-- I just wanted to solve it with programming.
Also, the use of Python is a great idea-- how can I get started with integrating Python into Excel? I'm very unfamiliar with Excel, but Python is something I have a handle on.

Comment: Since you need to transform your data (similar to SQL queries), it seems to me that pandas library is the best choice for you to try Python for Excel. It will not take you long to become efficient with pandas (I see that you are C guru). One weekend the longest :). But than you will be able to process Excel data outside Excel.